# High(er) current AC flasher circuit

Tags: transistors, ac, oscillator, lighting, diac

I'm trying to develop a flasher circuit for an aircraft warning light like the one shown [here](https://flightlight.com/products/obstruction-lights-controls-faa-l-810/). The light will be powered with 120 VAC providing 15 A.

I'd like to use transistors (BJTs, MOSFETs, thyristors, DIACs, TRIACs, etc.) to cause the light to flash (turn on and off at a given frequency).

Along those lines, I found several examples of transistor-based flasher circuits online, such as [this one](https://www.electroschematics.com/4488/diac-controlled-led-flasher/).

However, those circuits all seem to be intended for powering LEDs, which, I assume, have a lower current draw than the light I'm intending to use. Along those lines, I have a couple of questions:

1. Will the circuit I linked to above work with the light I'm powering? If so, what modifications do I have to make to accommodate the higher current levels in the light I'm using?
2. If this circuit does work, how do I modify the frequency of the flashing? I know it's possible to control that frequency by changing the values of the resistors and capacitor, but I don't remember the formula to do this.
3. In the diagram for the circuit I found, it looks like the capacitor voltage has been set to 100 V, presumably due to the value of the resistors. How do I calculate the voltage for that capacitor for a different resistor value?

Comment: Have you looked at the electronic flasher units that were used in cars? while 12v it may give you a stable design...

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you linked to is for low power use. The 10uF capacitor provides little energy. All the current for the load (the led) goes through the diac, which has limited capability.

For higher power you may want to look at strobe lights. They work on the same principle as far as the timing goes, but the timing circuit triggers a SCR that them conducts and discharges a much larger capacitor through a xenon flash tube.

[image]

http://www.free-electronic-circuits.com/circuits/strobe-light.html

This is a basic circuit. It will give a lot more output than the led circuit but still may be underpowered for your application. This is a simple circuit and a professional design would be a bit more involved because of the power required and the reliability needed for the application.

It is recommended that pulse grade capacitors be used. Photoflash capacitors are designed to discharge into flash tubes but they are not designed for the repetitive cycles that a strobe uses.

With higher powers it is desirable to have an inductor in series with the flash tube to control the peak current at the start of a discharge cycle.

There is a lot of engineering that goes into this type of device. (or there should be) There is a lot of information available on the internet, some of it is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Powering a flashing circuit directly off the AC line is difficult compared to other approaches.  Consider a low voltage flasher circuit such as something using a 555 (there are tons of examples online) powered by a wall wart, that drives a solid state relay to handle the light voltage and current.  More parts and larger assembly, but way easier - and way WAY safer - for someone with your experience level to handle.

Note:  That is not a dig.  Your questions indicate that you don't know how the circuit you linked to actually functions, and that indicates your experience level.  Line-powered circuit are so dangerous that some forums forbid discussing them.  Commercial products that do what you want must comply with many pages of safety standards, and pass audits to make sure the produced item is as safe as the design submitted for compliance testing.

What is the range of flash frequencies?

What is the duty cycle (ratio of on time to off time).  Does it also need to be adjustable, or can it be fixed at 50/50, 66/33, etc?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this question was for a school project a couple of years ago, so I'm no longer trying to try to figure this out anymore. That said, I appreciate  your providing this information.

Comment: Oops.  I wonder why it was near the top of the list of active topics ...

Comment: @AnalogKid Probably "Community bump", based on "At least one answer, but nothing upvoted"

Answer (score 0):

You can use solid state relays for the lights, they will work with a voltage of 3-about 32 VDC on the control side and the load side (AC side) upwards of 400V or more depending on the unit. They can be gotten in relative high amperage (more then 15A) at a low cost. You can purchase or build a simple flasher circuit to control the relays. Being solid state they will turn on at the zero cross eliminating a lot of the switching noise. If you are adventurous there are many Arduino projects that will do what you want just change the LEDs on them to the Solid State Relays (SSR).